# Dickey-Fuller test: conflicting results between SAS and R

Tags: r, sas, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm doing a Dickey-Fuller test on Airplane data in R. I'm using `adf.test` in "tseries" package and also doing this test in SAS. But SAS calculates p-value 0.2 and R calculates p-value 0.01. **Both alternative hypotheses are stationary in SAS and R**.

Question is: why does this happen? Why SAS and R output are so different? Thanks.

Here is my code and output in R:

```
library(tseries)
adf.test(AirPassengers)

        Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

    data:  AirPassengers
    Dickey-Fuller = -7.3186, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.01
    alternative hypothesis: stationary

    Warning message:
    In adf.test(AirPassengers) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

Comment: Try `adf.test(AirPassengers, k=0)`. According to the documentation, this is the standard Dickey-Fuller test. By default, `k=trunc((length(x)-1)^(1/3))`.

Comment: @JasonMorgan I check this before! but makes no difference in p-value! But I checked this for lags greater than '10', and makes different suddenly! 
for 'lag=9' p-value is '0.04' and for 'lag=10' p-value is '0.8'.

Comment: And what is the default in SAS?

Comment: @JasonMorgan SAS default is 'lag=1'.